# react-native: how can I convert output of Object.assign to a valid json format?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =
    {
      selectedDropDownValue:[]
    };
  }

func(itemName,itemValue)
      this.setState({
          selectedDropDownValue: Object.assign(this.state.selectedDropDownValue, {[itemName]: itemValue})
      });
}
```

and

```
func("size",null);
func("color","white");
```

when I logged it, I get somthing like this:

```
console.log(this.state.selectedDropDownValue);
```

> [size: null, color: "white"]

I want something like this:

> {"size": null, "color": "white"}

I want to send it to a PHP server, But it is not a valid JSON code.

how can I convert it to a JSON format before sending it to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedDropDownValue));
```

Comment: I test it before. it retun null.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code?

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =
    {
      selectedDropDownValue:{}
    };
  }

func(itemName,itemValue)
      this.setState({
          selectedDropDownValue: {"size": itemName, "color": itemValue}
      });
}
```